# BLEU measure in perl

Tags: perl, similarity

everyone.

I have seen a question raised by someone regarding Bleu method in java.. I do have the same problem. I just want to use Blue measure for simple sentence comparison. But i use perl programming. So, I just need an idea about blue and if possible a reference link to learn bleu method easily and completely.

Any help is appreciatable..

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps you should start by searching for this yourself, then come back with coding questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about [BLEU score implementation for sentence similarity detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390397/bleu-score-implementation-for-sentence-similarity-detection), then you might want to read this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLEU) and the answers in the SO question.