# Calculate BLEU score in Python

Tags: python, nltk

There is a test sentence and a reference sentence. How can I write a Python script that measures similarity between these two sentences in the form of BLEU metric used in automatic machine translation evaluation?

Comment: Other than BLEU, if you wanna use MT metrics for similarity: http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2015/cdrom/pdf/SemEval015.pdf

Answer (score 23):

The BLEU score consists of two parts, modified precision and brevity penalty.
Details can be seen in the [paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P02-1040.pdf).
You can use the [`nltk.align.bleu_score`](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/align/bleu_score.html) module inside the NLTK.
One code example can be seen as below:

```py
import nltk

hypothesis = ['It', 'is', 'a', 'cat', 'at', 'room']
reference = ['It', 'is', 'a', 'cat', 'inside', 'the', 'room']
#there may be several references
BLEUscore = nltk.translate.bleu_score.sentence_bleu([reference], hypothesis)
print(BLEUscore)
```

Note that the default BLEU score uses n=4 which includes unigrams to 4 grams. If your sentence is smaller than 4, you need to reset the N value, otherwise `ZeroDivisionError: Fraction(0, 0)` error will be returned.
So, you should reset the weight like this:

```py
import nltk

hypothesis = ["open", "the", "file"]
reference = ["open", "file"]
#the maximum is bigram, so assign the weight into 2 half.
BLEUscore = nltk.translate.bleu_score.sentence_bleu([reference], hypothesis, weights = (0.5, 0.5))
print(BLEUscore)
```

Comment: Does this work if I pass numbers (word indices in the vocabulary) instead of the actual words in the arrays?

Comment: @AshutoshBaheti I think that it should be the same as the the number is as meaningful as the word. So it should work well.

Answer (score 12):

You are actually asking for **two different** things. I will try to shed light on each of the questions.

**Part I: Computing the BLEU score**

You can calculate BLEU score using the BLEU module under `nltk`. See [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/align/bleu.html).

From there you can easily compute the alignment score between the candidate and reference sentences.

**Part II: Computing the similarity**

I would not suggest using the BLEU score as similarity measure between the first candidate and second candidate if you aim to measure the similarity based on the reference sentence.

Now, let me elaborate this. If you calculate a BLEU score for a candidate **against a reference**, then this score would merely help you understand the similarity between another canditate's BLEU score against the reference sentence, even though the reference sentence remains the same.

If you intend to measure the similarity between two sentences, [word2vec](https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/) would be a better method. You can compute the angular cosine distance between the two sentence vectors to understand their similarity.

For a thorough understanding of what **BLEU** metric does, I'd suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5409525/170671) as well as [this](http://rare-technologies.com/making-sense-of-word2vec/) for **word2vec** similarity.

Comment: instead of word2vec, a more advanced doc2vec (or any other sentence embedding) would be a better aproach to find the sentence similarity

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use the python package [SacréBLEU](https://github.com/mjpost/sacreBLEU) (Python 3 only):

> SacréBLEU provides hassle-free computation of shareable, comparable, and reproducible BLEU scores.
>   Inspired by Rico Sennrich's `multi-bleu-detok.perl`, it produces the official WMT scores but works with plain text.
>   It also knows all the standard test sets and handles downloading, processing, and tokenization for you.
>
> Why use this version of BLEU?
>
> - It automatically downloads common WMT test sets and processes them to plain text
> - It produces a short version string that facilitates cross-paper comparisons
> - It properly computes scores on detokenized outputs, using WMT ([Conference on Machine Translation](http://statmt.org/wmt17)) standard tokenization
> - It produces the same values as official script (`mteval-v13a.pl`) used by WMT
> - It outputs the BLEU score without the comma, so you don't have to remove it with `sed` (Looking at you, `multi-bleu.perl`)

To install: `pip install sacrebleu`

Answer (score 4):

The following is the code for calculating `Bleu` score between two files.

```
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu
import argparse

def argparser():
    Argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    Argparser.add_argument('--reference', type=str, default='summaries.txt', help='Reference File')
    Argparser.add_argument('--candidate', type=str, default='candidates.txt', help='Candidate file')

    args = Argparser.parse_args()
    return args

args = argparser()

reference = open(args.reference, 'r').readlines()
candidate = open(args.candidate, 'r').readlines()

if len(reference) != len(candidate):
    raise ValueError('The number of sentences in both files do not match.')

score = 0.

for i in range(len(reference)):
    score += sentence_bleu([reference[i].strip().split()], candidate[i].strip().split())

score /= len(reference)
print("The bleu score is: "+str(score))
```

Use the command `python file_name.py --reference file1.txt --candidate file2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I can show some examples of how to calculate BLEU score if test and reference sentences are known.

You can even take both sentences as input in the form of a string and convert to lists.

```
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu
reference = [['the', 'cat',"is","sitting","on","the","mat"]]
test = ["on",'the',"mat","is","a","cat"]
score = sentence_bleu(  reference, test)
print(score)


from nltk.translate.bleu_score import sentence_bleu
reference = [['the', 'cat',"is","sitting","on","the","mat"]]
test = ["there",'is',"cat","sitting","cat"]
score = sentence_bleu(  reference, test)
print(score)
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone using tensor flow. You have to calculate y_true and y_pred..

Example :

ENGLISH INPUT (y_true some vector of following sentence) - I loved the movie very much.

FRENCH OUTPUT (y_pred some vector of following sentence and you can use tf.argmax() for getting highest probability) - j'ai beaucoup aimé le film

```
class BLEU(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

def __init__(self, name='bleu_score'):
    super(BLEU, self).__init__()
    self.bleu_score = 0

def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    y_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred, -1)
    self.bleu_score = 0
    for i, j in zip(y_pred, y_true):
        tf.autograph.experimental.set_loop_options()

        total_words = tf.math.count_nonzero(i)
        total_matches = 0
        for word in i:
            if word == 0:
                break
            for q in range(len(j)):
                if j[q] == 0:
                    break
                if word == j[q]:
                    total_matches += 1
                    j = tf.boolean_mask(j, [False if y == q else True for y in range(len(j))])
                    break

        self.bleu_score += total_matches / total_words

def result(self):
    return self.bleu_score / BATCH_SIZE
```